Occurs bug when communicating Arduino and Raspberry PI throug Serial
I am working with Arduino and i am having problem when communicating from Raspberry PI to Arduino. I have two motor drivers (bts7960B) that connected to the Arduino. And with Serial i am trying to control arduino (like start motor, reverse motor) with Raspberry PI. I connected my wireless controller and i am sending command to arduino with Python. My code sending "w" for forward and "r" to reverse and when joystick button relased i am sending "r" for stop my motors. For sending command i am using pyserial. And inside of Arduino gets commands with Serial.read() and applying commands and settings motors pwms. But sometimes I think there is an error in my Arduino and it stays on the last command sent to the Arduino. When the problem occurs, if "w" is sent last, my Arduino acts as if this command is being sent all the time. And that's why the motors are constantly running. And when I look at the tx led on my Arduino, nothing happens. So I couldn't understand what exactly happened to my Arduino here. Can you help me with this?
Here is my Python control code:
import serial
import pygame
import time
import threading

# Arduino setup
arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/arduino1', 115200)

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()

# Check if joystick is connected
if pygame.joystick.get_count() == 0:
    print("No joystick connected")
else:
    # Initialize joystick
    joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
    joystick.init()

    def arduino_movement():
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.JOYHATMOTION:
                    if event.value == (0, 1):
                        arduino.write(b'w')
                    elif event.value == (0, -1):
                        arduino.write(b's')
                    elif event.value == (1, 0):
                        arduino.write(b'd')
                    elif event.value == (-1, 0):
                        arduino.write(b'a')
                    elif event.value == (0, 0):
                        arduino.write(b'r')
                    print(event)

            time.sleep(0.1)  # Small delay to make output readable


    # Start threads
    try:
        arduino_thread = threading.Thread(target=arduino_movement, daemon=True)

        arduino_thread.start()

        # Keep the main program running
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Program interrupted")

    finally:
        pygame.joystick.quit()
        pygame.quit()
        print("Pygame and joystick resources released")



And here is the Arduino code:
#define L_EN1 2
#define R_EN1 4
#define L_PWM1 5
#define R_PWM1 6

#define L_EN2 8
#define R_EN2 10
#define L_PWM2 11
#define R_PWM2 9

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(L_EN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(R_EN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(L_PWM1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(R_PWM1, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(L_EN2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(R_EN2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(L_PWM2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(R_PWM2, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(L_EN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(R_EN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(L_EN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(R_EN2, LOW);
}

void motor1Forward(int speed)
{
  digitalWrite(L_EN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(R_EN1, HIGH);
  analogWrite(R_PWM1, 0);
  analogWrite(L_PWM1, speed);
}

void motor1Reverse(int speed)
{
  digitalWrite(L_EN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(R_EN1, HIGH);
  analogWrite(R_PWM1, speed);
  analogWrite(L_PWM1, 0);
}

void motor2Forward(int speed)
{
  digitalWrite(L_EN2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(R_EN2, HIGH);
  analogWrite(R_PWM2, 0);
  analogWrite(L_PWM2, speed);
}

void motor2Reverse(int speed)
{
  digitalWrite(L_EN2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(R_EN2, HIGH);
  analogWrite(R_PWM2, speed);
  analogWrite(L_PWM2, 0);
}

void stopMotors()
{
  digitalWrite(R_EN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(L_EN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(L_EN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(R_EN2, LOW);
  analogWrite(R_PWM1, 0);
  analogWrite(L_PWM1, 0);
  analogWrite(R_PWM2, 0);
  analogWrite(L_PWM2, 0);
}



void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) 
  {
    char command = Serial.read();

    

    if (command == 'w') {
      motor1Forward(255);
      motor2Forward(255);

    }
    else if (command == 's') {
      motor1Reverse(255);
      motor2Reverse(255);

    }
    else if (command == 'a') {
      motor1Reverse(255);
      motor2Forward(255);
    }
    else if (command == 'd') {
      motor1Forward(255);
      motor2Reverse(255);
    } 
    else if (command == 'r') {
      stopMotors();
    }

    Serial.flush();

  } 
}

Thank you in advance for your help!

Serial.flush(); only clears the buffer for outgoing data not for incoming data.
To clear the buffer for incoming data, use serial.read();.


But sometimes I think there is an error in my Arduino and it stays on the last command sent to the Arduino.

Nothing you've written gives a hint whether the problem is on the sending side or the receiving side. Serial port communication is notoriously noisy e.g. bytes get lost or bits get changed. Maybe your control code stopped sending data, or maybe corrupted bytes are arriving at the arduino.

When the problem occurs, if "w" is sent last, my Arduino acts as if this command is being sent all the time.

The standard way to prevent this dangerous situation is to make the arduino timeout each command after a short time, say 250 milliseconds. If a new "run motors" command does not come in, then the motors are automatically stopped.
